# Change percentage legend colour of lightweight-charts-python

Tags: python, lightweight-charts

I was implementing [**lightweight-charts-python**](https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python) library that is python equivalent for tradingview's lightweight-charts library.

In that I wanted to have a label showing open, high, low, close and percentage move of the candle that the crosshair was pointing to.

I found the way to add these labels from [here](https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python#5-styling) but there was no way to change the colour of all labels or only the percentage label dynamically according to the crosshair's candle's colour.

Is there any workaround or a proper solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell this color cannot be set dynamically from the outside.

A quick hack to get the desired behaviour:

- Locate the func.js javascript file located in your local copy at `lightweight_charts/js/funcs.js`
- Modify line 232 from

  ```js
  let percent = `| ${percentMove >= 0 ? '+' : ''}${percentMove.toFixed(2)} %`
  ```

  to

  ```js
  let percent = `| ${percentMove >= 0 ? '<span style="color: green">+' : '<span style="color: red">'}${percentMove.toFixed(2)} %</span>`
  ```

This should change the color of the percentage label dynamically from green (+) to red (-) (or any color of your choosing, if you have the [css skills](https://www.quackit.com/css/css_color_codes.cfm))

[image]

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was thinking, but due to lack of interest in java script, didn't continue.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just the addition to [christian-karcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77542210/14004940)

For anyone wondering about the steps, following are those:

1. Open your mac terminal, run command:
   `$ cd /`
2. After that, run:
   `$ find . -iname "*lightweight_charts*"`
3. you will get output as following:

   ```
   ...
   ...
   ./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightweight_charts
   ...
   ```
4. cd to that folder:

   ```
   $ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightweight_charts/
   ```
5. Open the js file that christian-karcher mentioned in his answer, in the code editor of your choice, for me is visual editor code:
   `$ code js/funcs.js #this command opens funcs.js in visual studio code`
6. Find the line with the following code:

   ```
   let percent = `| ${percentMove >= 0 ? '+' : ''}${percentMove.toFixed(2)} %`
   ```

   and replace it with:

   ```
   let percent = `| ${percentMove >= 0 ? '<span style="color: green">+' : '<span style="color: red">'}${percentMove.toFixed(2)} %</span>`
   ```

Now just re-run your code and see the percentage label change colour according to candle that the crosshair is pointing to.